# Allowing cookies from a specific site in Safari

Tags: safari, cookies

I'm a new Mac user and I have a financial site which says I must allow cookies...and I'm okay with that, I just don't know how to do that. I've looked in my settings and preferences but it appears I have to allow cookies for everyone or no one at all. Would someone be able to help me? I'd rather not add additional programs if I can avoid it... OS X must be able to do this, right?

Comment: What version of OS X and Safari are you using?

Comment: Any solutions to this that work with the current macOS and Safari?  (The solution below doesn't work (and lacks detail too) as the Privacy tab has changed for the worse.  Extensions, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Safari's** settings and from there you can allow certain sites to leave cookies.  There are several other settings worth investigating here too.

To get to settings, from the Menu click **Safari** > **Preferences...** and go to the **Privacy** tab.

[image: Cookies in Safari settings]

Comment: I realize it's been 6 years, but is there an updated version of this answer? It doesn't seem to work any more.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 If you're getting told that cookies must be allowed, the website should correct it. Most browsers are standardizing blocking 3rd party cookies, which was the original question here.

Comment: The website I'm trying to use is a two-factor authentication site. It has a checkbox for "remembering" my browser for 30 days, or basically storing a cookie on my system. This process works fine in Google Chrome, but doesn't work in Safari, meaning I have to use the 2FA every single time I log in.